# How to replace the value of a string within two characters in php

Tags: php, replace

Good morning everyone,
I need to figure out if there is a way to change the values inside the * *.

Example:

```
Hello everyone, this is my 1st post.
*photo1*
*photo2*
*photo3*
See you soon...
```

and replace the code with:

```
Hello everyone, this is my 1st post.
*photo*
*photo*
*photo*
See you soon...
```

without number after the word photo

How it works currently:

I have a txt file that contains the words photo1, photo2, photo3 between asterisks. This file is read via the file_get_contents command and I would need to remove the number at the end of the word photo.

Comment: A little more information would help us to help you. Can you tell us how the original  `*photo1*` for example gets placed into that html

Comment: Sure, I'd like to point out that all those tags don't actually exist they've just been placed here on stackoverflow to give formatting to the text. What comes out is reading a txt file.

I just want to replace *photo1*, *photo2* by removing the number at the end of the word photo

Comment: ___YES I know what you said you want to do___ the first time, repetition does not inprove understanding alone. I am trying to find a place that makes sense in the page build flow where it would be sensible to do this

Comment: I find myself in the post a -2 points when in reality it is explained very well.
I have a txt file that contains the words photo1, photo2, photo3 between asterisks. This file is read via the file_get_contents command and I would need to remove the number at the end of the word photo. More than that I don't know how to explain it

Comment: AHh so show the code where you read the text file. THAT YOU DIDNT MENTION in the question, or show the code for. That sounds like a place where code can be run, unlike a simple piece of HTML

Comment: _"when in reality it is explained very well"_ - You have explained what you want using some very (overly?) simplified example (from the looks of it), but when posting here, it's good to try to give some real example data and show before/after. If we get some real example data, we might be able to help tailor an answer for your specific needs, instead of something generic that might not even fit 100%. Either way, you should add your attempts as well and explain where they go wrong. We'r glad to help you sort issue out but we're not here to do all the work for you.

Comment: the file reading question is not important... I just asked: I have this text/code, is there a way to replace the number after the word photo? I didn't ask anyone to do the work for me, I just asked if there is a php code where I can read and do it myself..

Answer (score 1):

You can use `preg_replace` for that. E.g:

```
$str = '*photo9*';

echo preg_replace('/\*photo[0-9]+\*/', 'photo', $str);
```

Output:

> photo

Note. `\` is to escape the asterisk `*` in the expression, because it has a special meaning without it – you need to match the literal asterisk.

This may be more simple (depending on what you are trying to do):

```
echo preg_replace('/\d/', '', $str);
```

Note. `\d` stands for digit, and will target numerals from `0-9`. A more concise equivalent would be `/[0-9]+/` – The `+` means "one or more" characters must be a digit.